# Get headers from http response

Tags: elm

I am new to elm, 
I have a login api which returns a JWT token in its hedears

```
curl  http://localhost:4000/api/login?email=bob@example&password=1234
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXyLp0aSI6ImefP2GOWEFYWM47ig2W6nrhw
x-expires: 1499255103
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

success
```

now Im trying to write a function that will send request and return the token from the headers in elm

```
authUser =
    Http.send "http://localhost:4000/api/login?email=bob@example&password=1234"
```

how do I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 14):

In order to extract a header from a response, you will have to use `Http.request` along with the [`expectStringResponse`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#expectStringResponse) function, which includes the full response including headers.

The `expectStringResponse` function takes a `Http.Response a` value, so we can create a function that accepts a header name and a response, then returns `Ok headerValue` or `Err msg` depending on whether the header was found:

```elm
extractHeader : String -> Http.Response String -> Result String String
extractHeader name resp =
    Dict.get name resp.headers
        |> Result.fromMaybe ("header " ++ name ++ " not found")
```

This could be used by a request builder like so:

```elm
getHeader : String -> String -> Http.Request String
getHeader name url =
    Http.request
        { method = "GET"
        , headers = []
        , url = url
        , body = Http.emptyBody
        , expect = Http.expectStringResponse (extractHeader name)
        , timeout = Nothing
        , withCredentials = False
        }
```

[Here is an example on `ellie-app.com`](https://ellie-app.com/3prFNXVLfdSa1/0) which returns the value of `content-type` as an example. You can substitute `"authorization"` for your purposes.

Comment: i keep on getting: 
BadPayload "header authorization not found" { status = { code = 200, message = "OK" }, headers = Dict.fromList [("cache-control","max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"),("content-type","text/plain; charset=utf-8")], url = "http://localhost:4000/api/login?email=bob@example&password=1234", body = "success" }

when I use `curl` I do get the authorization header

Comment: It looks like that dictionary is case sensitive. You could try logging the list of dictionary keys (using `Dict.keys`) to see whether you are using the right casing.

Comment: dictionary seems to contain only part of the headers:  [ ("cache-control"),("content-type")]

Comment: [Here is a simple web server and working Elm example](https://github.com/freakingawesome/stackoverflow-44368340) that shows  that an Authorization in the response header can be retrieved by Elm. Are you sure your Elm test app is pointed at the same url as your `curl` example? ([image of output](https://www.screencast.com/t/1Wlgq861))

Comment: You would compile and run with [`Go`](https://golang.org/doc/install) (run via `go run main.go` after running `elm make Main.elm` in the public dir), but really, you could write a simple server endpoint in any language to see the authorization header. It's not specific to Go; that was just quick for me to whip up as an example.

Answer (score 3):

May I humbly suggest you look at my elm-jwt library, and the [get](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/simonh1000/elm-jwt/5.0.0/Jwt#get) function there?

```
Jwt.get token "/api/data" dataDecoder
    |> Jwt.send DataResult
```

JWT tokens normally need to be sent as a `Authorization` header and this function helps you create a Request type that can be passed to `Http.send` or `Jwt.send`

Comment: thanks for your help! my request is a simple request **without** headers, the response has headers - and I am trying to get the **response** headers